# Hibernate Criteria query for one to may relationship entity giving duplicate data

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-criteria, join

There is class called Parent and i have properties called attributes and details.One parent can have may properties and similarly one parent can have many details.

```
class Parent{
@Id
@GeneratedValue
int parentId;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "attributeComposite.parentId", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Attributes> attributes = new HashSet<>();

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "detailsComposite.parentId", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Details> attributes = new HashSet<>();

}
```

Now i have entered data like parent have **2 attributes** and **4 details**.I want to retrieve the data from criteria query which has parentId **1**.So i am querying like this

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Parent.class);
            criteria = criteria.add(Restrictions.idEq(1));
criteria = criteria.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
tempMapping = (Parent) criteria.uniqueResult();
```

Which is returning only one parent with parent id **1**.But it has **4 attributes** instead of 2 and **4 details**.I think its joining the child data by joining each other. So how to get the complete parent entity data with out changing anything in childrens?

Comment: It might be useful to set "hibernate.show_sql=true" in hiber config and look at the plain SQL produced by your criteria.

Comment: i have checked that its joining and returning data. there will be 4 attributes(2 original attributes and 2 duplicates) and 4 details(there will be no duplicates here). whether we have to add any thing extra to criteria query?